# How to make multiple div on same page to appear only once per browser session. (Javascript code)

Tags: javascript, html

Need to show the div only once, but not able to set a different cookie for multiple div.

```js
function closeNotice() {
 $("#hidebox").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

```html
<body>
<html>
<div id="hidebox">
    <div class="text-content cmp-close-icon hidden-xs welcome">
        <a class="close-notify" onclick="closeNotice()">X</a>
        <h1 class="title1">Hello World</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="hidebox">
    <div class="text-content cmp-close-icon hidden-xs welcome">
        <a class="close-notify" onclick="closeNotice()">X</a>
        <h1 class="title1">Hello World</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like perhaps you want [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)?

Comment: Where are you setting the different cookies?

Comment: Also you have mutiple div with same ids and HTMl will not behave correctly. you should have unique ids only.